# How can I repeat my pattern with a minor change?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my pattern, [`\/\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/2s3Wgh/1/). It matches the slash and number which is in the end of string. Now I want to expand it and making it working for a sequence of them.

Here is the input:

```
ticket/2/1/19
```

And here is the **current** result:

```
ticket/2/1
```

And this is the **expected** result:

```
ticket
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is `ticket` really the expected (desired) result? Or is it `/2/1/19`?

Comment: Yes @ClasG, I want to strip that string from all `/<digit(s)>` which are at the end of it.

Comment: OK, I see. The "strip" part wasn't mentioned in the question though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap `\/\d+` with a [grouping construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and quantify the group:

```
(?:\/\d+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eOLu4Y/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

  - `\/` - a `/`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `)+` - end of the group, repeated 1 or more times (`+`)
- `$` - end of string.